# How to use a function as event handler and to be directly called, with parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

In a jQuery script I have a function that normally gets called in response to a click, so acts as an event handler, but I also need to call it directly. In both cases it needs some parameters.

So, the situation, simplified, is this:

```
function go(e) {
  console.log(e.data.dir)
}

$("body").keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 37) { // left
    go({dir: 'forward'});
  } else if (e.which == 39) { // right
    go({dir: 'forward'});
  }
});

$('.forward').on('click', {
  dir: 'forward'
}, go);
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ehL1smde/4/)

This clearly doesn't work because when I call the function directly there's no `data` key.
A workaround would be to call the function like this:

```
go({data: {dir: 'forward'}});
```

And it works, but is pretty ugly.
What would it be the right approach in such a case?

Comment: What about `console.log((e.data || e).dir)` ?

Comment: Perhaps you want to [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the keydown event on the body element, and pass in a custom [event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) object ...? (See the second example on the event page, that is about triggering a keydown event, and it passes in a specified keyCode.)

Comment: `go({data: {dir: 'forward'}});` is perfectly okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, you can solve the issue with `apply()` and just pass along the arguments from the event handler if the condition is truthy

```
function go(e) {
    console.log(e.data.dir)
}

$("body").on('keydown', {dir: 'forward'}, function(e) {
    if (e.which === 37 || e.which === 39) {
        go.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});

$('.forward').on('click', {dir: 'forward'}, go);
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ehL1smde/6/)

Or you could pass in an object with the matching properties

```
$("body").on('keydown', {dir: 'forward'}, function(e) {
    if (e.which === 37 || e.which === 39) 
        go({data:{dir: 'forward'}});
});
```

or trigger the click event with a custom event

```
$("body").on('keydown', {dir: 'forward'}, function(e) {
    if (e.which === 37 || e.which === 39) 
        $('.forward').trigger('click', [{data: {dir: 'forward'}}] );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways I can see this going.

- You could store you parameter object in a variable at the top of your script, and pass the variable to `go()` when you need to call it outside of a click handler.  That would make things a little less ugly.
- Or you could check if `e` is null inside `go()`, and if it is, use/set some generic default.

Either would be acceptable, depending on what all the method has to do.

Answer (score 2):

I think I would do something like this (unless I need the event):

```
function go(data) {
    console.log(data.dir)
}

$("body").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 37) { // left
        go({dir: 'forward'});
    } else if (e.which == 39) { // right
        go({dir: 'forward'});
    }
});

$('.forward').on('click', function(){
    go({dir: 'forward'});
});
```